iOS SwiftUI keyboard pushing makes texts folded
Can we simply push every content above the textfield to the top without folding text lines?

Here is my body code.
var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack(spacing: 24) {
                if DeviceUtil.getDeviceType() != .smallPhone {
                    Image(systemName: "sun.min.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 220, height: 46)
                    Image(systemName: "building.2")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: DeviceUtil.getDeviceType() == .iPad ? 350 : 200, height: DeviceUtil.getDeviceType() == .iPad ? 240 : 150)
                        .padding(.top, 24)
                } else {
                    Image("bLogo")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 34)
                    
                    Image("companyIntro")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 140)
                        .padding(.top, 12)
                }
                
                Text("One place\nfor all your work.")
                    .font(.titilliumWebRegular(size: DeviceUtil.getDeviceType() == .smallPhone ? 16 :  24))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.")
                    .font(.titilliumWebRegular(size: 15))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 1)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                .padding(.horizontal, DeviceUtil.getDeviceType() == .normalPhone ? 64 : 34)
                mainContent
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .background {
            Image("companyLaunch")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }


You can wrap your view in ScrollView for your content got push up without getting clipped:
ScrollView {
    ZStack(alignment: .top) {
        ...
    }
}


ZStack(alignment: .top) {
ScrollView {
...
}
}
is better for me.
